# update only the blank cells in my array in google appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a function where it will lookup the cells in an array that are blanks and will not overwrite the existing data in my sales data sheet

```
function DOLOOKUP_1(d) {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const wsSalesData = ss.getSheetByName('Sales Data'); //dest data wsSalesData
  var wsRates = ss.getSheetByName('Rates'); //source data wsRates
  
  // 2,2  same value row column-1 of dest file -1,4 value to get source column
  const ratesData = wsRates.getRange(2, 2, wsRates.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  
  const searchValues = wsSalesData.getRange('C2:C').getValues();
  
  const matchingRates = searchValues.map(seachRow => {                                    
    const matchRow = ratesData.find(r =>  r[0] == seachRow[0]);
    return matchRow ? [matchRow[2]] : [null];
  });

  if( wsSalesData.getRange('H2:H').getValues() == null) {
    wsSalesData.getRange('H2:H').setValues(matchingRates); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please describe the problem you faced.

Comment: thank you!  When i run the script it doesnt lookup the values i have on the blank cells. i wanted to do the if function so that i would only lookup and update the cells that doesnt have any value yet in my sale data. Im using the app script in google so im trying to do this script for google sheets

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Relevant clarifications should be added directly into the post body as comments are intended to be temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `getValues()` and `setValues()`, enable and use sheets api. Setting `null` in sheets api skips the values instead of setting them. [Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) say

> For input, supported value types are: bool, string, and double. **Null values will be skipped**. To set a cell to an empty value, set the string value to an empty string.

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(
  {
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    data: [
      {
        range: 'Sales Data!H2',
        values: matchingRates,
      },
    ],
  },
  ss.getId()
);
```

Comment: To readers: The Advanced Sheets Service should be enabled to be able to use this code.